# How does drop system work in Dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

Valve has recently launched a virtual store in Dota 2 where you can buy various items for your hero. But I heard that is possible to "drop" this items also for free, in game.

How does this system works? Is it completely random? Is it possible to drop all items available in the store?

Comment: It works somewhat like TF2's drop system. I imagine that a key difference is that some items cannot be found via free random drops, and some items may not be available to buy from the store.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every time you reach a new level you are guaranteed to get an item. There is also a random chance to receive an item after every matchmaking game.

You cannot receive keys (to open treasure chests) through random drops, nor some exclusive items that can be found only by opening chests (unusual couriers, other mythical items, etc.).

Comment: hmm.. I leveled to 2 after 1 match (haven't played since before the leveling system), says I got an item, but nothing in my Dota 2 inventory?

Comment: No idea? Might be a delay, you might not have actually leveled up (getting to level 2 in just a single match doesn't make sense), or the system might be bugged right now.

Answer (score 0):

After every game you get Battle Points, when you get a certain amount you get a "drop".

Comment: I got a drop during my first match without even get battle points because all other team except one left.

Comment: This is a wrong statement. You do not get items after a certain amount of battle points. When you level up you are guaranteed an item, and the rest is random.

Comment: @Steven Actually it's right, after you get a certain amount (i. e. 1000), you get a drop.